# Woocommerce custom Product Type doesn't display on page reload

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a woocommerce custom product type. I have also defined custom tab and its contents. I am able to save all the data using `update_post_meta` and publish button. But the Product Type drop down always shows `Simple Product` when the page reloads (though my saved data is intact). This is not the case, if I save the product type as the woo commerce defaults (Simple, Variation etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not using woocommerce_product_class. Added below code, it worked

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_class', 'new_woocommerce_product_class', 10, 2 );
function new_woocommerce_product_class( $classname, $product_type ) {
    if ( $product_type == 'YOUR CUSTOM PRODUCT' ) { 
        $classname = 'YOUR CLASS NAME';
    }
    return $classname;
}
```